# How to check updates on dependencies?

Tags: jenkins

I have the following configuration on Jenkins (A, B, C and D are different projects on my repository):

```
   A
  / \ 
 B   C 
  \ / 
   D
```

I configured a build in jenkins starting with Project A, triggering builds B and C, and then starting build of the project D (using the Join Plugin).

But sometimes the following occurs:

- I commit some changes in project C and D.
- Jenkins identify first the change in project D and tries to build, but it fails.
- Then the change on project C is identified and build C is triggered.
- Join is not executed (because it is configured on build A).

Is there any way to make Jenkins, when it identifies any changes on D, check projects C and B before starting the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure jenkins not to build D before C finished using `Block build when upstream project is building`. But this is a problem that imho cannot be solved when using SNAPSHOT dependencies when all builds run at the same time. You additionally could trigger at a different time. E.g. Build A at HH:01, then build B,C at HH:02 and D at HH:03. As Jenkins waits to build the job until the upstream build is finished everything should work ...